# Displaying additional attribute in table - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My pivot table `admin_user` with additional attribute `item_no`. I am finding it hard to retrieve the additional attribute into my html table.

PS: i tried `$admin->pivot->item_no` in my table but i get an error `trying to get a non-object`

**Admin**

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('item_no')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**admin_food**

```
admin_id

user_id 

item_no
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
     {
         $admins = Admin::where('id',1)->get();

         return view('index',compact('admins'));
     }
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table" id="table"> 
<thead>
    <tr> 
    <th>Order No#</th>
    <th>Name</th>

    </tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($admins as $admin)
<tr >
<td>{{$admin->name}}</td>

</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does `item_no` exists on table ?

Comment: yes it exists on the table, please

Comment: Could you post your admin model?

Comment: Provide your model definition for `pivot` relation

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, please look at my model

Comment: @Hamoud, please check my update

Comment: How do you try to access item_id in your html? you remove the code after the edit?

Comment: @Hamoud, i don't understand you

Comment: Your definition looks fine just curious what is the output of `dd($admins)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the item_id by access the pivot property of the user/related model.

Your controller is returning a collection that has only one admin.

```
     $admins = Admin::where('id',1)->get();
```

`admins` will be a collection of 1 admin that has id = 1.

if this was on purpose, then you can access the item_id for every user related to this admin by this code:

```
@foreach($admins as $admin)
    @foreach($admin->users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->pivot->item_id}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

To simplify:

```
$admin = Amdin::first();
$item_id = $admin->users()->first()->pivot->item_id
```